# Importing/adding a yum .repo file using Ansible

Tags: ansible, yum, vagrant-provision

I'm trying to install MariaDB (or any software) from a custom repository using Ansible but I am not sure how to import the .repo file using the yum/[yum_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html) modules.

### Ansible

Here is my playbook:

```yaml
-
    hosts: all
    become: true
    remote_user: root
    tasks:
        -
            name: set system timezone
            timezone:
                name: America/Toronto
        -
            name: add custom repository
            yum_repository:
                name: centos_o
                description: custom repositories
                baseurl: http://example.net/mirror/centos_o.repo
        -
            name: ensure mariadb is installed
            yum:
                name: mariadb-server-5.5.*
                state: installed
```

I've tried all `include`, `metalink`, `baseurl`, and `mirrorlist` with no luck. Also I am missing the GPG key step, but I can't even get the repo added properly.

The centos_o.repo file looks like this:

```
# JENKINS
[jenkins]
name=CentOS-$releasever - JENKINS
baseurl=http://example.net/mirror/jenkins/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1

# MariaDB 5.5
[mariadb]
name=CentOS-$releasever - MariaDB
baseurl=http://example.net/mirror/mariadb/yum/5.5/centos$releasever-amd64/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1

# MariaDB 10.0
[mariadb]
name=CentOS-$releasever - MariaDB
baseurl=http://example.net/mirror/mariadb/yum/10.0/centos$releasever-amd64/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
```

### Shell

This is the shell script version that I am trying to convert to Ansible:

```
yum clean all
yum-config-manager --add-repo=http://example.net/mirror/centos_o.repo
yum-config-manager --enable mariadb
rpm --import http://example.net/mirror/mariadb/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
```

If it makes any difference, I am running this with Vagrant's [Ansible local](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html) provisioner on a CentOS box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It [appears](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/yum_repository.py#L627-L629) that you are correct, they don't offer what you are after. Their model is such that you would call `yum_repository:` 3 times, once with each of the `baseurl=` values you already have in your `.repo` file.

Thus, given your circumstance, I'd recommend just using `command:` to run the `yum-config-manager --add-repo` just as you are in shell. The only catch to that would be if `yum-config-manager --add-repo=` isn't idempotent, in which case you'd have to guard that `command:` by hand to keep it from adding that same repo file over and over with each run.

Comment: Guarding the command in this case can be done by checking for the existence of the `centos_o.repo` file, or is there a better way?

Comment: Regrettably I don't know, but _presumably_ `yum-config-manager` has a `--list-repo` or equivalent functionality so you can see what's up that way. I don't have a CentOS system to try it out to say for sure

Answer (score 25):

Use the shell command with the creates flag. That will skip the step if the repo file exists.  You'll need to make sure you know what the repo file is called.

```
- name: Add CentOS_o repository
  shell: yum-config-manager --add-repo=http://example.net/mirror/centos_o.repo
  args:
    creates: /etc/yum.repos.d/centos_o.repo
```

If you need to add any architecture to the url use something like

```
- name: Add CentOS_7_speciality repository
  shell: yum-config-manager --add-repo=http://example.net/{{ ansible_distribution | lower }}/{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}/{{ ansible_architecture }}/
centos_o.repo
  args:
    creates: /etc/yum.repos.d/centos_o.repo
```

Ansible will replace the variables with

```
{{ ansible_distribution | lower }} == centos
{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }} == 7
{{ ansible_architecture }} == x86_64
```